# Creating a Shape from a Drawable without pixel transparency in Android

Tags: java, android, shapes, rect

I'm trying to create a Shape or a Rect from a Drawable but without the transparency of the Drawable.

As you can see here, the following button has transparency on its borders. My issue is that I'm creating a panel Editor and I want to avoid superposition of widget when I move a widget. 
To achieve this, I have used the method : `Rect.intersects(Rect)`

[image]

However, the Rect used is the shape of the entire drawable(with the transparency) and it's create too much empty space.

EDIT: more informations

Here is my Editor, I succed to avoid superposition but the superposition is base on the Shape of the drawable (picture). And the picture's tranparency create some empty space on my panel.

[image]

and my check collision code, where tempRect is the current Moving widget

```
public boolean checkCollision(Rect tempRect,ArrayList<IHMObject> listWidget) {
    float dimen = activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height)+ 38;
    for(IHMObject widget  :listWidget ){
        int[]location = new int[2];
        View v =(View)widget.getView();
        v.getLocationInWindow(location);
        //vérifier la postion du widget en fonctions des autres widgets de l'IHM
        Rect staticRect = new Rect(location[0],location[1]-(int)dimen,location[0]+v.getWidth(),location[1]+v.getHeight()-(int)dimen);
        if (this.id!=widget.id){
            if (staticRect.intersect(tempRect)) {
                //il y a une collision entre les deux rectangles
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a round_shape.xml file in drawable folder like below


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
    <solid android:color="#ABABAB"/> 
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>

Set this Draweble like below

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:src="@drawable/round_shape" // here is your round_shape
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="Buttons" />
```

Comment: I probably wasn't enough clear, i need to create a Shape or Rect from an existing picture saved as Drawable BUT without the transparency of the picture